# Identify COLLSCAN from mongo db c# driver 2.7.3

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using mongodb driver 2.7.3 and I would like to know if FindAsync() method can give me an execution plan to identify if the query is indexed or un-indexed.

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Finds the documents matching the filter.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   filter:
        //     The filter.
        //
        //   options:
        //     The options.
        //
        //   cancellationToken:
        //     The cancellation token.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   TProjection:
        //     The type of the projection (same as TDocument if there is no projection).
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Task whose result is a cursor.
        Task<IAsyncCursor<TProjection>> FindAsync<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter, FindOptions<TDocument, TProjection> options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

The size of the response could be large, so I want the cursor to iterate through the results.

OR

Is there any other way that I can use to identify if this query resulted in COLLSCAN or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) in mongo shell.

```
db.collection.find({}).explain("executionStats")
```

or

```
db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate([])
```

This will list all the parameters and execution plan of the query including:

```
- query plan (winning plan and rejected plans)
- index used (if any)
- time took to execute query in milliseconds
- keys scanned and documents scanned and many more.
```

Comment: I am aware about the shell command. I want to achieve it from the C# driver.

Answer (score 0):

Using driver version `2.0+` you should be able to specify `$explain` as a [find option with your query](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1250?focusedCommentId=898728&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-898728). The object in the response here should be a standard explain BSON response object. So you'll need to make sure that if you want to use it that you can deserialize it.

```
var options = new FindOptions
{
    Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$explain", true)
};
var explain = await collection.Find(x => true, options)
    .Project(new BsonDocument())
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Optionally, you can specify the find options in [a different way](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/commit/6f237b66e70e35c11d2d7bbce3efa49d2dd1ea25#diff-711f156ad048902da243b1ef654a40fb). Something like this;

```
_collection.FindAsync<BsonDocument>(
            filter,
            Arg.Is<FindOptions<T, BsonDocument>>(options => hasExpectedProjection(options)),
            CancellationToken.None);
```